# ¿Cómo hago que una sesión PHP expire después de 30 minutos?

Tags: php

Necesito mantener una sesión viva durante 30 minutos y luego destruirla. Y quiero saber cual es la mejor forma de hacerlo.

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado para que otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema te ayuden!, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: la mejor forma respecto a qué criterio?

Comment: Mi lenguaje principal es java y en distintos caso, utilizando servlets, frameworks (como vaadin, spring, etc), jsf... para cada situación hay una forma particular de setear dicha información. Lo que necesito saber es, en este caso de PHP puro (sin frameworks involucrados) como realizar un manejo correcto del session time out. (es una aplicación simple, pero de gran importancia a nivel de seguridad)